# Flutter Firebase Version Solving Failed - Expert Please Specify Version

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Because cloud_firestore_web 0.2.1+2 depends on http_parser ^3.1.3 and no versions of cloud_firestore_web match >0.2.1+2 <0.3.0, cloud_firestore_web ^0.2.1+2 requires http_parser ^3.1.3.
And because http >=0.13.0 depends on http_parser ^4.0.0 and cloud_firestore 0.14.4 depends on cloud_firestore_web ^0.2.1+2, http >=0.13.0 is incompatible with cloud_firestore 0.14.4.
So, because markets depends on both cloud_firestore 0.14.4 and http 0.13.2, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because markets depends on both cloud_firestore 0.14.4 and http 0.13.2, version solving failed.)

I am new in flutter, please help me to solve this issue

```
name: markets
description: markets

version: 2.0.0+9

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
module:
  androidX: true
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: 1.0.2
  google_maps_flutter: 1.2.0
  google_map_location_picker: 4.1.6
  mvc_pattern: 6.6.4+2
  global_configuration: 2.0.0-nullsafety.0
  html: 0.14.0+4
  shared_preferences: 2.0.5
  flutter_html: ^1.2.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.19.3
  location: 3.0.2
  webview_flutter: 1.0.7
  url_launcher: 6.0.2
  firebase_messaging: 7.0.3
  cached_network_image: 2.5.0
  fluttertoast: 8.0.1-nullsafety.0
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.4.0-nullsafety.3
  intl_utils: 1.9.0
  carousel_slider: 4.0.0-nullsafety.0
  cloud_firestore: 0.14.4
  firebase_auth: 0.18.4+1
  firebase_core: 0.5.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.17.0
  http: 0.13.2

flutter:

  assets:
    - assets/cfg/
    - assets/img/

  fonts:
  - family: ProductSans
    fonts:
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Thin.ttf
        weight: 100
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Thin.ttf
        weight: 200
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Light.ttf
        weight: 300
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Regular.ttf
        weight: 400
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Medium.ttf
        weight: 500
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Bold.ttf
        weight: 600
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Black.ttf
        weight: 700
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Black.ttf
        weight: 800
      - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Black.ttf
        weight: 900
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running 'Flutter pub upgrade'. You can type the command in your terminal window in Android Studio. Or if you open your pubspec.yaml file, you'll see the Pub upgrade command along the top, next to Pub get. Running the command will get the newest versions of your libraries and will probably resolve the issue.

If that doesn't work, then try running 'Flutter pub outdated' and 'Flutter pub upgrade --major-versions'.

**Edit:**

This returns 'Pub get' without error:

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6
  #google_map_location_picker: 4.1.7
  mvc_pattern: ^7.4.0
  global_configuration: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.1
  html: ^0.15.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
  flutter_html: ^2.1.0
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  location: ^4.3.0
  webview_flutter: ^2.0.9
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  firebase_messaging: ^10.0.3
  cached_network_image: 2.5.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.7
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.4.0
  intl_utils: 2.3.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: 1.3.0
```

I had to comment out google_map_location_picker because that is an outdated library. The author of that library appears to have abandoned the project. google_maps_place_picker might be a suitable alternative.

Comment: I ran the pub get and pub upgrade. Both showed me the same error as mentioned above. When I run the outdated one. It doesn't show anything on screen. Just a blank screen

Comment: Check my updated answer. I commented out incompatible libraries until Pub get returned clean. Then I started uncommenting libraries and running Pub get and upgrade. The only library I couldn't get to work was google_map_location_picker.